# Install a 32-bit JRE on Windows 64-bit platform

Tags: 64-bit, java-native-interface, java

I have a Windows 2008 64-bit server and I have to install a 32-bit JRE, because my Java application uses 32-bit DLLs using JNI.

Unfortunately the `java.exe` is installed to `C:\Windows\SysWow64` and when I start a console window or a batch file the installed `java.exe`is not found. (Because `cmd.exe` is a 64-bit application and sees the 64-bit version of the system directory which has no `java.exe`)

How can I make the installed `java.exe` available to batch files and the command line without to much messing around with the system configuration, causing other problems or preventing future updates to the JRE?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Don't rely on the `java.exe` that's in a Windows system directory; add the `bin` directory of your Java runtime environment to the `PATH` environment variable (if that's not too much "messing around with the system configuration").

Comment: That would require updating the path variable every time a new JRE is installed to reflect the different folder name.

Comment: OK, I spoke to soon. Only the *JDKs* have different folder names each release. For the JRE it's always `jre6`. So your answer is the perfect solution :)

Comment: You obviously need to install a JRE from Oracle first, in case that is not clear. (Tried to edit that substantial missing step into the answer, but was rejected in peer review as too minor edit... StackOverflow peer review process needs to be overworked!)

Answer (score 2):

Known issues when you install a 32 -bit JRE on a 64- bit Windows architecture machine:

1. Online Installation and Java Update features are not applicable to 64-bit architecture
2. The public JRE installed with the 32-bit JRE is not registered. You must set the PATH environment variable to point to JAVA_HOME \bin to register the JRE

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/install-windows-64-142952.html